# append in array pymongo

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

i want to update `bookmarks` array by id of `_id_collection`.

```
result = collections.find_one({"_id": ObjectId(id)},
        { 'array_of_collections': { '$elemMatch': { '_id_collection': ObjectId('5e9871582be940b6af4a9b41') }}})
print(result) # {'_id': ObjectId('5e986b4a07b94384ae8016b7'), 'array_of_collections': [{'_id_collection': ObjectId('5e9871582be940b6af4a9b41'), 'name_of_collection': 'test2', 'bookmarks': []}]}
```

here is my code of result of searching this object, now i can append in `bookmarks` array some values, but i don't know how to do it.
on this picture u can see my monbodb structure.
[image: mongodb structure]

Comment: have you tried using `update_one`?

Comment: @MarkPotter yes, like that ```collections.update_one(
           {"_id": ObjectId(id)},
           { 'array_of_collections': { '$elemMatch': { '_id_collection': ObjectId(id_of_collection) }}},
           { '$push': { 'array_of_collections': { 'bookmarks': 'test' } } }
        )```

Comment: where is ```collections``` is ```collections = database.someCollection```

Comment: Oh man I see, you want to push something into a specified bookmarks array, which itself is inside an array. Not gunna lie my friend I think this data structure could use some work. If you must stick with this I suggest making modifications to the doc in your python code then just doing `$set` in your update and overwriting the whole `array_col_collections`

Comment: @MarkPotter update '$push' field to '$set' and my code returning now this error ```ValueError: update only works with $ operators```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do the `$elemMatch` as part of the query and then use the positional operator `$`, you can successfully push values to your desired bookmarks array.

Try this:

```py
import pprint

from bson import ObjectId
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient()
db = client.tst1
coll = db.coll6

coll.update_one({"_id": ObjectId("5e9898c69c26fe7ba93476f6"),
                 'array_of_collections': {'$elemMatch': {'_id_collection': ObjectId("5e9898c69c26fe7ba93476f4")}}},
                {'$push': {'array_of_collections.$.bookmarks': 'Pushed Value 1'}})

mlist1 = list(coll.find())

for mdoc in mlist1:
    pprint.pprint(mdoc)
```

Result Document:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5e9898c69c26fe7ba93476f6'),
 'array_of_collections': [{'_id_collection': ObjectId('5e9898c69c26fe7ba93476f2'),
                           'bookmarks': [],
                           'name_of_collection': 'test'},
                          {'_id_collection': ObjectId('5e9898c69c26fe7ba93476f3'),
                           'bookmarks': [],
                           'name_of_collection': 'test2'},
                          {'_id_collection': ObjectId('5e9898c69c26fe7ba93476f4'),
                           'bookmarks': ['Pushed Value 1'],
                           'name_of_collection': 'test3'},
                          {'_id_collection': ObjectId('5e9898c69c26fe7ba93476f5'),
                           'bookmarks': [],
                           'name_of_collection': 'test4'}]}
```